# Image Button Confirmation on Delete

Tags: asp.net, button, confirm

I would like to ask my delete button to ask for confirmation before deleting a row. How to I carry this out?

```
<dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="3" ButtonType="Image" Width="10px">
    <DeleteButton Visible="True" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, Delete %>" >
        <Image   Url="../Resources/Imgs/Erase.gif" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, Delete %>" />
    </DeleteButton>
    <HeaderCaptionTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxButton runat="server" ID="ButtonAddNew" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, Add %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:GlobalResource, Add %>" Image-Url="~/Resources/Imgs/Add.gif" AutoPostBack="False">
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { OperationsGrid.AddNewRow(); }" />
        </dx:ASPxButton>
    </HeaderCaptionTemplate>
</dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I have understood correctly your question (you want a confirmation message before performing delete, right?), I have used, for a similar feature, OnClientClick button property as follows:

```
  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDel" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/delete-button.jpg" ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick ="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?');"/>
```

Also, in code behind, in order to check which button of the confirm box was pressed (ok/cancel), I had the following code:

```
    if (btnDel.CausesValidation == true)    //ok was pressed.
       {
             //perform delete.
       }
```

Later Edit:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientInstanceName="GridView1" >
    <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="function(s, e) {     
              e.processOnServer = confirm('Do you really want to apply changes?'); }" />        
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: Yes i wanted to add a confirm but i am not using native Asp i am using DevExpress is there a way to do it with DevExpress